# Java "while != null" reads last line as null

Tags: java

I am trying to run the following code using a batch file of URLs, while the URL is not null. It runs exactly how I want it to, however, the last line of output reads:

Malformed URL Exception: 'null' is not a valid input

Batch Program Completed Successfully

I want the program to stop right before it actually reads the null. Any suggestions?

(Also, I am still learning how to ask questions without people getting mad at me so if I can improve my question, just let me know instead of down voting. Thanks.)

```
private static String getBatchUrlContents(String filePath) {
        logger.debug(">>getBatchUrlContents()");
        String theUrl = "";
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
            BufferedReader bufferedUrlReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            do {
                try {
                    theUrl = bufferedUrlReader.readLine();
                    URL url = new URL(theUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                String contentType = urlConnection.getContentType();
                logger.info("Content Type: {}", contentType);
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                logger.info("Status Code: {}", statusCode);


                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    contents.add(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                String[] contentArray = contents.toArray(new String[contents.size()]);
                System.out.println("\n ~~~~~~~NEW URL~~~~~~~ \n" + theUrl);
                for (String x :contentArray)
                    System.out.println(x);

                String firstLine = contentArray[0];

                if (firstLine.equals("#EXTM3U")) {
                    logger.info("First line is validated: {}", firstLine);
                    System.out.println("First line of content is validated: " + firstLine);
                } else {
                    logger.error("Error: First line not valid: {}", firstLine);
                    System.out.println("Error: First line reads: '" + firstLine + "'\n"
                            + "Should read: '#EXTM3U'");
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof MalformedURLException) {
                    logger.error("Malformed URL Exception: {}", e.toString());
                    System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception: '" + theUrl + "' is not a valid input");
                } else if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
                    logger.error("404: File Not Found Exception: {}", e.toString());
                    System.out.println("Unable to open URL: " + theUrl);
                } else if (e instanceof IOException) {
                    logger.error("IO Exception: {}", e.toString());
                    System.out.println("Error reading file: " + theUrl);
                } else {
                    logger.error("Exception: {}", e.toString());
                    System.out.println("Exception Error - Unable to read or open: " + theUrl);
                }
            }
        } while (theUrl != null);
        bufferedUrlReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + filePath + "'");
        System.exit(2);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + filePath + "'");
        System.exit(3);
    }
    logger.debug("<<getUrlContents()");
    return "Batch Program Completed Successfully";
}
```

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to convert your `do-while` loop into a `while` loop. This way the `null` check executes before further manipulations of the parsed value. Of course, you can also explicitly check for `null` before you create the `URL`.

Comment: @Mena That won't help here, as the check is still happening before the assignment. Unless you did the assignment inside the condition.

Comment: The loop condition is checked at the *end* of your loop, which means that it's checking against the value that you previously read, and not the next line.  What you're attempting is better done in a standard while loop, and not a do-while loop.  Just call `theUrl  = bufferedUrlReader.readLine()` before the loop, and then use a standard while loop, where you read in the next line at the very end of the loop body.

Comment: @Carcigenicate true, I should have specified that the check needs to be in a form such as `while ((line = blah.readLine()) != null)`.

Comment: `bufferdReader.readLine()` is never `null`. You should be checking for `(line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != -1`. Because whoen a line is null (or the file is end) `BufferedReader` returns -1.

Comment: @ Omid She's right. `readLine` does return `null`. It can't ever be -1 as the type of the return is `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `theUrl != null` check happens at the end of the loop; it isn't checked continuously.

If you need `theURL` to be non-`null`, you'll need to check for that.

You could do the assignment in the condition (although this is frowned upon in some circles):

```
while((theUrl = bufferedUrlReader.readLine()) != null) {
    URL url = new URL(theUrl);
    ...
```

or, just do a check inside the loop and do a manual `break`:

```
while(true) {
    theUrl = bufferedUrlReader.readLine();

    if (!theURL) { // Or "if (theURL == null)"
        break;
    }

    URL url = new URL(theUrl);
    ...
```